# How can i develop a fish tank automation using arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

As a part of my final year Engineering project I would like to develop a  fish tank automation system. In my project I need to check the quality  of water concurrently and also I need to check the sedimentation of my fish tank. Which are the different types of sensors  used for this?
How can i connect it to my arduno uno?

Comment: Have you tried googling for corresponding sensors? What were the results and how exactly didn't they help you? What have you already tried to design your project?

Comment: what does `quality of water` mean? ... what factors are you checking? ... what does `sedimentation` mean? ... what are you checking?

Comment: you can check turbidity with a shielded light sensor and a light emitter; like an analog beam interruption sensor.

Comment: You can try water temperature controlling idk if you are in a winter season having zone in earth like auto turning on the heater, can auto turn on UV light when dark etc.or may be filter status by connectivity measurements or pH level you have to draw a diagram of what you will do before going to electronic programming.what will you do so on

Answer (score 4):

You're starting from the wrong end of the problem (the electronics).

First, you need to decide the requirements for your system.

- Write down what your system is supposed to do: measure something? When & how often? Save or display the measurements? Control something based on the data? How precise must that control be (e.g. +/- .5 degC) (precision can be expensive)? Control something based on something other than measurements (except, perhaps, time?
- Once you understand the requirements, then you can write down the steps the system should take to meet them; it doesn't need to be code (and probably shouldn't be, just yet).
- Decide on what to measure and how to measure it. Can't figure out a sensor for something? Maybe you can infer it from something you can sense. Or perhaps learn how quickly or how often that 'something' goes out of spec and restore it without a measurement (e.g. you presumably already know how often and how much to food to dispense).
- Now you can start thinking about electronics, sensors, and code, having a pretty good idea of what you will need to know, to acquire, and to create, to build your project (whether or not you'll be expected to actually build one).

This is an Engineering approach to design and it is almost certain your project is intended to show that you know how to do this, much more than to show you can run a fish tank.